# Bash foor loop change the directory from one location to anther location

Tags: bash

Here the my directory Tree. Each directory A, B, C contains specific user.txt file respective to the user name.

Now I want to switch to each directory A, B, C and need to zip only usera.txt, userb.txt, userc.txt into the respective folder and delete the source file (.txt file)  from the directory after taking zip file.

```
┌──(root㉿DESKTOP-1OOLTMI)-[/home/gowmi]
└─# tree
.
├── UserA
│   └── usera.txt
├── UserB
│   └── userb.txt
└── UserC
    └── userc.txt

4 directories, 3 files
```

my for loop

```
PATH1=/home/gowmi/UserA/*

for file in $PATH1*; 
do
    zip ${file%.*}.zip $file -mT .; 
done

PATH2=/home/gowmi/UserB/*

for file in $PATH2*; 
do
    zip ${file%.*}.zip $file -mT .; 
done

PATH3=/home/gowmi/UserC/*

for file in $PATH3*; 
do
    zip ${file%.*}.zip $file -mT .; 
done
```

I can see above script is not a reusable and i can see we have code duplication as well for repeating the for loop. Can you please some guide me how i can make it better way.

NOTE: and also if its possible we can take recursively zip file each directory and file as well. like below.

Comment: `for i in A B C; do echo "do your stuff here with $i"; done`

Comment: I do not understand what you want to say in your note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops can nest.

The first step would be:

```
for path in /home/gowmi/UserA /home/gowmi/UserB /home/gowmi/UserC ; do
    for file in $path/* ; do 
        zip ${file%.*}.zip $file -mT .; 
    done
done
```

When you get more users, you can:

```
for path in /home/gowmi/User* ; do
```